# Multiple (distinct) workspaces per monitor

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, 22.04, gnome-tweaks

`Ubuntu 22.04 / Gnome 3 + tweaks`.

I am looking for a way, to have a "distinct group of workspaces per monitor", just like MacOS does (I think it's an incredible productivity increasing feature). However, I can't seem to find a way (or a theme for that matter) which does this

Basically the following:

- **Laptop** with a group (`g1`) of `i` workspaces: `L_1, ..., L_i`.
- **Monitor "a"** with a group (`g2`) of `k` workspaces: `M(a)_1, ..., M(a)_k`.
- **Monitor "b"** with a group (`g3`) of `n` workspaces: `M(b)_1, ..., M(b)_n`.

I would like to be able to have "distinct" groups of workspaces per monitor, which I'll be swiping through depending on where my cursor is.

Thoughts?

Comment: Not possible... see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/37 for a 4 year old request on this. and also see this one https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2021/02/23/gnome-shell-40-and-multi-monitor/